# Looking for JS chart library with interactive diagrams

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

In my project I work on a web app that shall provide interactive charts to the user. Interactive is meant in that way that the user can adjust single data points by dragging them around in chart.

More specifically, assume a line chart consisting of six data points. The user clicks one data point and drags it to different coordinates within the chart (drag and drop). Afterwards the line should be rendered again considering the adapted coordinates.

I had a look into Chart.js already but found that this feature is **not** provided out-of-the-box. I rather have to implement that myself.

Are you aware of any chart library for JS that provides such feature?

**UPDATE**

Meanwhile I found two potential solutions:

- [Plugin for Highcharts](https://github.com/highcharts/draggable-points)
- [Draggable charts of FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/drag-able-charts/introduction.html#types-of-drag-able-charts)

Comment: I know this thread is old, but in case anyone stumbles upon this, I wrote a small plugin for chart.js called [chartjs-plugin-dragData](https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragData) which essentially has the requested features. The method was described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757979/chart-js-drag-points-on-linear-chart

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), it's battery-included and drag&drop is supported too.

But you have to make the chart in HTML/CSS yourself.

Comment: I also took a look at D3, however I consider the effort to draw the chart myself as relatively high and would prefer a to use a chart library.